# How to receive "user-Id" on IoT Hub messages

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I'm using EventHubTrigger and EventData to receive IotHub message and  I want to get "user-Id" in EventData.SystemProperties. Follow https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct 
I set Message.UserId by Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client, but I still can not receive it in EvenData.SystemProperties

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you use the code: Message msg = new Message { UserId = "FooUser" }? Which language did you use?

Answer (score 0):

The following screen snippets show an example of the *user-id* property on the telemetry data.

1. The virtual device (represented by my [Azure IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1254463/Azure-Event-Grid-Tester)) is publishing a telemetry data with systemproperty *$.uid=ABCD1234*

[image]

2. The telemetry data are receiving by azure function:

   ```
   public static void Run2([IoTHubTrigger("messages/events", Connection = "AzureIoTHubConnectionString")]EventData message, ILogger log)
   {
       log.LogInformation($"\nBody:\n\t{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.Array)}" +
                          $"\nSystemProperties:\n\t{string.Join("\n\t", message.SystemProperties.Select(i => $"{i.Key}={i.Value}"))}" +
                          $"\nProperties:\n\t{string.Join("\n\t", message.Properties.Select(i => $"{ i.Key}={ i.Value}"))}");          

       log.LogInformation($"user-id={System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(((ArraySegment<byte>)message.SystemProperties["user-id"]).Array)}");
   }
   ```
3. The azure function log:

[image]

Note, that the value type of the *user-id* systemproperty is

```
ArraySegment<byte>
```